# DMI, Stochastic RSI and RSI adding together

Tags: pine-script

I already have a pine-script running DMI, Stochastic RSI and RSI together successfully. But I have found a community script of DMI which gives better and smoothed signal. But while I am trying to add the new DMI it is giving the following error -

> Add to Chart operation failed, reason: Variable `SmoothedTrueRange` is
> already declared.

My code is as follows -

```
study("ADX and DI for v4")
len = input(14)
th = input(20)

TrueRange = max(max(high-low, abs(high-nz(close[1]))), abs(low-nz(close[1])))
DirectionalMovementPlus = high-nz(high[1]) > nz(low[1])-low ? max(high-nz(high[1]), 0): 0
DirectionalMovementMinus = nz(low[1])-low > high-nz(high[1]) ? max(nz(low[1])-low, 0): 0

SmoothedTrueRange = 0.0
SmoothedTrueRange = nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1]) - (nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1])/len) + TrueRange

SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus = 0.0
SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus = nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus[1]) - (nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus[1])/len) + DirectionalMovementPlus

SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus = 0.0
SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus = nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus[1]) - (nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus[1])/len) + DirectionalMovementMinus

DIPlus = SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus / SmoothedTrueRange * 100
DIMinus = SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus / SmoothedTrueRange * 100
DX = abs(DIPlus-DIMinus) / (DIPlus+DIMinus)*100
ADX = sma(DX, len)

plot(DIPlus, color=color.green, title="DI+")
plot(DIMinus, color=color.red, title="DI-")
plot(ADX, color=color.navy, title="ADX")
hline(th, color=color.black)

//Stochastic RSI
smoothK = input.int(3, "K", minval=1)
smoothD = input.int(3, "D", minval=1)
lengthRSI = input.int(14, "RSI Length", minval=1)
lengthStoch = input.int(14, "Stochastic Length", minval=1)
src = input(close, title="RSI Source")
rsi1 = ta.rsi(src, lengthRSI)
k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(rsi1, rsi1, rsi1, lengthStoch), smoothK)
d = ta.sma(k, smoothD)
plot(k, "K", color=#2962FF)
plot(d, "D", color=#FF6D00)
h0 = hline(80, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
h2 = hline(70, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
h3 = hline(60, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
h4 = hline(50, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
h5 = hline(40, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
h6 = hline(30, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
h1 = hline(20, "Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(h0, h1, color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 90), title="Background")

//RSI
len = input.int(14, minval=1, title="Length",group="RSI setting")
src_rsi = input(close, "Source",group="RSI setting")
up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(src), 0), len)
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(src), 0), len)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
plot(rsi, "RSI", color=#7E57C2)
band1 = hline(70, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
bandm = hline(50, "Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
band0 = hline(30, "Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(band1, band0, color=color.rgb(126, 87, 194, 90), title="Background")
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks & regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `:=` operator to assign values to variables after initialization.

Also, this is a mix of v4 and v5. Better upgrade it to v5.

Here it is:

```
//@version=5
indicator("ADX and DI for v4")
len = input(14)
th = input(20)

TrueRange = math.max(math.max(high-low, math.abs(high-nz(close[1]))), math.abs(low-nz(close[1])))
DirectionalMovementPlus = high-nz(high[1]) > nz(low[1])-low ? math.max(high-nz(high[1]), 0): 0
DirectionalMovementMinus = nz(low[1])-low > high-nz(high[1]) ? math.max(nz(low[1])-low, 0): 0

SmoothedTrueRange = 0.0
SmoothedTrueRange := nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1]) - (nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1])/len) + TrueRange

SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus = 0.0
SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus := nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus[1]) - (nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus[1])/len) + DirectionalMovementPlus

SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus = 0.0
SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus := nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus[1]) - (nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus[1])/len) + DirectionalMovementMinus

DIPlus = SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus / SmoothedTrueRange * 100
DIMinus = SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus / SmoothedTrueRange * 100
DX = math.abs(DIPlus-DIMinus) / (DIPlus+DIMinus)*100
ADX = ta.sma(DX, len)

plot(DIPlus, color=color.green, title="DI+")
plot(DIMinus, color=color.red, title="DI-")
plot(ADX, color=color.navy, title="ADX")
hline(th, color=color.black)

//Stochastic RSI
smoothK = input.int(3, "K", minval=1)
smoothD = input.int(3, "D", minval=1)
lengthRSI = input.int(14, "RSI Length", minval=1)
lengthStoch = input.int(14, "Stochastic Length", minval=1)
src = input(close, title="RSI Source")
rsi1 = ta.rsi(src, lengthRSI)
k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(rsi1, rsi1, rsi1, lengthStoch), smoothK)
d = ta.sma(k, smoothD)
plot(k, "K", color=#2962FF)
plot(d, "D", color=#FF6D00)
h0 = hline(80, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
h2 = hline(70, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
h3 = hline(60, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
h4 = hline(50, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
h5 = hline(40, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
h6 = hline(30, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
h1 = hline(20, "Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(h0, h1, color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 90), title="Background")

//RSI
rsi_len = input.int(14, minval=1, title="Length",group="RSI setting")
src_rsi = input(close, "Source",group="RSI setting")
up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(src), 0), rsi_len)
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(src), 0), rsi_len)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
plot(rsi, "RSI", color=#7E57C2)
band1 = hline(70, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
bandm = hline(50, "Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
band0 = hline(30, "Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(band1, band0, color=color.rgb(126, 87, 194, 90), title="Background")
```